# Get author user ID using Parse.Query not current user

Tags: javascript, node.js, parse-platform, ionic4, parse-server

I have two parse classes, User and Place.
If user ads a place, user is added as Pointer to the Place user column.
In order to list all places and determine how many places has a user, i use the following query:

```
loadTotalPointsDetail(params: any = {}): Promise<Place[]> {
const page = params.page || 0;
const limit = params.limit || 100;

const query = new Parse.Query(Place);

query.equalTo('user', Parse.User.current());

query.skip(page * limit);
query.limit(limit);
query.include('category');
query.include('user');
query.doesNotExist('deletedAt');

return query.find();
}
```

Filtering by Parse.User.current()) i will get current user places.

[image]

If i don't filter by Parse.User.current()) it will return all places as  objects, containing all data.

[image]

How can i filter by place real author / user? not current (loggedIn)?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```js
loadTotalPointsDetail(params: any = {}): Promise<Place[]> {
  const page = params.page || 0;
  const limit = params.limit || 100;

  const query = new Parse.Query(Place);

  const user = new Parse.User();
  user.id = 'The id of the user that you want to search for';
  query.equalTo('user', user);

  query.skip(page * limit);
  query.limit(limit);
  query.include('category');
  query.include('user');
  query.doesNotExist('deletedAt');

  return query.find();
}
```

Comment: Hello, the id should be auto populated, in the place table there is a user, i want to retrieve that user. I want to query place user owner ID and extract all his published places.

Comment: I am supposing you want to query by some user id, right? That's what my answer is about. I've just edited it to include the complete code so you can better understand.

Comment: The user.id from the query should be the place.user.id. Imagine a blog post, there is a title, description and author. I need to group all author posts in order to show more from this author. From the console i can see the author id but i can't access it from loadTotalPointsDetail query. The app should automatically get the author id and search for more posts from that author. That's why get current it's not suitable for me.

Comment: I am not proposing you to get the current. Take a look in my answer. You know the user id of which you want to see the places, right?

Comment: No, that's the point, if i knew the user id i could match it in query. But the user ID from loadTotalPointsDetail, must be the place user name witch is the user id.

Comment: If i put manually the user id in the query from above i get all the posts from that user ID, but if the user changes, there will be no results. So i need to auto populate the place id in order to match in query with user id.

Comment: You question is "How can i filter by place real author / user?". That's the query that you need to use in order to retrieve all places by its author. It is not clear to me what more you want to achieve. If you can explain, I will probably be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I'll post the solution here, not the most indicated but it works for me:

```
  async loadData() {

try {

  const places = await this.placeService.loadTotalPointsDetail(this.params);
  const placeU = await this.placeService.loadPlaceU(this.getParams().id);

  for (const place of places) {
    this.places.push(place);
  }
  let u = placeU.user.id;
  let totalUserPlaces = places.filter(x => x.user.id == u);
  if (totalUserPlaces) {

    /* The total returned by reduce() will be stored in myTotal */
    const myTotal = totalUserPlaces.reduce((total, place) => {    

        /* For each place iterated, access the points field of the 
        current place being iterated and add that to the current
        running total */
        return total + place.points;

    }, 0); /* Total is initally zero */
this.points = myTotal;
} else {}
} catch (err) {

  const message = await this.getTrans('ERROR_NETWORK');
  this.showToast(message);}}
```

so i'm loading two separate queries:

```
const places = await this.placeService.loadTotalPointsDetail(this.params); -> Gets all posts listings
const placeU = await this.placeService.loadPlaceU(this.getParams().id); --> Gets the ID for current post
```

I extract the user post ID:

```
let u = placeU.user.id;
```

I filter using that user in order to get his posts:

```
let totalUserPlaces = places.filter(x => x.user.id == u);
```